# Django REST framework: get field of related model in serializer

Tags: python, django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django Rest Framework. I'm trying to get my `ListAPI` to show various fields of my `Quiz` (and related) models. It's working fine, except for my `attempt_number` field. I'm getting the right queryset, but I'm not sure how to get only the relevant value for every query. Users can take every quiz as many times as they want, and I want to show the queryset for each attempt, since the score etc. will be different.

My model setup is as follows:

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    questions_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Question(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField('Correct answer', default=False)

class QuizTaker(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    correct_answers = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    attempt_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

My serializer for the `ListAPI` looks as follows:

```
class MyQuizListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    attempt = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    # etc..
    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        fields = "__all__"

    def get_attempt(self, obj):
        try:
            quiztaker = QuizTaker.objects.filter(user=self.context['request'].user,
                quiz=obj)
            for attempt in quiztaker:
                attempt_number = attempt.attempt_number
            return attempt_number
```

If I do it like this, I always get the last value for `attempt_number` (because the loop overwrites the value). So then I tried to append it to a list instead, like this:

```
a = []
for attempt in quiztaker:
    attempt_number = attempt.attempt_number
    a.append(attempt_number)
return a
```

But then I get the list of attempts for every query, instead of the attempt number for each query. I.e. I get the following three times (because in this case there are three attempts):

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "attempt": [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ]
},
```

But instead what I want is (and the same for attempt 2 and 3 etc.):

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "attempt": 1
},
```

So I tried doing it like this:

```
return a[attempt_number-1]
```

Hoping it would give me index zero for attempt number 1, 1 for 2, etc. But then I still just get the last attempt number (3 in this case). How can I solve this?

I also tried just using an `IntegerField` instead of a `SerializerMethodField` as follows:

```
attempt = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True, source='quiztaker.attempt_number')
```

But it returned nothing.

Comment: You want the ***first*** value?

Comment: I want the relevant value for every query, so 1 when it's the first attempt, 2 when it's the second, and so on @ArakkalAbu

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind the *relevant* word. Can you explain the logic?

Comment: Every user can take the quiz as many times as they want, so there isn't just one `quiztaker` per user for every quiz, but `n`, where `n=number of attempts`. So I want every query to show what attempt number it is.

Comment: that is you want the *total attempt* taken by a user on a specific `Quiz` ?

Comment: No, I want a different query for every attempt, because each will have a different score etc. @ArakkalAbu

Comment: as you said in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63751319/django-rest-framework-get-field-of-related-model-in-serializer#comment112734346_63751319), there are ***`N`*** attempts for ***each `Quiz`***. What I understood is, you want to get a ***single-value `X`*** from the related `QuizTaker`. What is the logic behind the ***process of "picking" that "sing-value"***? I would highly recommend showing some data in the OP would probably make the question easier to understand.

Comment: return the length of the list if you just want to show the number of attempts. e.g.return Len(a)

Comment: No, because then if there are for example `n` attempts, it will just give me `n` `n` times, but I want a different queryset for every attempt. @UmairLakhani

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I correctly understood you, you want the list of attempts added to each quiz object.

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "attempts": [{
        "id": 1,
        "attempt_number": 1,
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "attempt_number": 2,
    }...]
}
```

In that case, you should have a separate serializer for the `QuizTaker` model and serialize the objects in the `SerializerMethodField`.

```
class QuizTakerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = QuizTaker
        fields = ('id', 'attempt_number')
 
class MyQuizListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    attempts = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    # etc..
    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        fields = "__all__"

    def get_attempts(self, obj):
        quiztakers = QuizTaker.objects.filter(user=self.context['request'].user,quiz=obj)
        return QuizTakerSerializer(quiztakers, many=True).data
```

Honestly, your question is not very clear and it would help to edit it and make it clearer, giving the JSON structure you want to achieve. I also suspect your intended use of `queryset` isn't the actual Django meaning for a *container* of ORM objects.

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly. Thanks for your answer, I will try it out later, and if it doesn't work, will try to edit my question to make it clearer. @Ken4scholars

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. Just one follow-up question, it's giving me all the fields for `QuizTaker` even though I specify the `id` and `attempt_number` fields in the serializer... why is that and how can I fix it? @Ken4scholars

Comment: That is strange. Can you edit your original question to post the serilalizer code?